# "Measure" vs. "measurement"

Tags: word-choice, differences, nouns, word-usage

*Measure* has a lot of meanings, but I am not sure whether it is or is not a partial synonym of *measurement*.

Let's say that I have an algorithm, and I measure its execution time under different conditions, hence obtaining different execution times. How do I call those execution times I have measured: *measures* or *measurements*?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Inasmuch as it's relevant to this context, a [measure](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/measure) is the standard, system, or unit by which something is measured, *e.g.*,

> Philosophers have long pondered the true measure of a man.
>
> The standard measure of distance is the meter.

or an unstated or undefined amount, *e.g.*,

> This recipe calls for a measure of egg for texture.
>
> She failed to show any measure of sympathy.

A [measurement](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/measurement) is the datum or numerical value obtained by measuring, *e.g.*,

> His measurements are off by an order of magnitude.

Either word can serve as the act of measuring.

> His measure(ment) of the frequency failed to account for the red-shift in the observations.

For your example,

> The measure of this algorithm's performance is its execution time.  Therefore, our testing suite gathers measurements of the execution under different runtime conditions.  Our testing suite itself adds overhead that will not be present in a deployment environment, however, and this must not be forgotten when we analyze its measure(s/ment/ments) of the underlying algorithm's performance.

Answer (score 4):

In normal usage, "measure" is a verb referring to the action of laying down a ruler or clocking a speed or whatever. "Measurement" is a noun that can be, (a) the act of measuring, or (b) the quantity to be measured or the result of measuring.

For example, "I measured the length of this piece of wood." (measure - verb) "I used a ruler to perform this measurement." (measurement - the action) "Please find the measurements of this room." "The measurement was 14 inches." (measurement - result)

English-speakers occasionally use "measure" as a noun for the result of measurement. Like, "The resulting measure was three liters." But this is a relatively rare. Most people say "measurement".

Comment: So, in short, I should call those execution times that I have measured *measurements*. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I guess I should have said that the first time.

Comment: "(b) the quantity to be measured" Does than mean than length is one measure and weight is another?

Comment: @RogerWernersson Yes.

Comment: @Jay Hmm. I have heard that from you and one other person, but failed to find a source. Can you link to a dictionary or encyclopedia which backs this up?

Comment: Maybe I need to back up a step and clarify what you're asking. If I measure my height and then I measure my weight, I have taken 2 measurements. Are you asking if that is properly said "height and weight are 2 measurements" versus "height and weight are a measurement"? If there are 2 of them, it seems to me that's obviously a plural, but maybe I'm missing your point.

Answer (score 3):

Numerical values that are measured are **measurements**, where I would define *measure* as "to express an observed magnitude in terms of defined units", and measurements are the numbers produced by the act of measuring (measurement). This is exactly what you are doing with your execution times.

The noun form of **measure** can refer to a value that indicates a characteristic, but is *not* strictly measured. For example, the [Gini coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) is a **measure** of a country' economic inequality. The value was not obtained by comparing some observable magnitude against a "Gini scale", it was calculated from multiple possibly subjective statistical samples.

Answer (score -1):

Measures are made up of really two types of measurements:

1. detections (commonly just called ‘measurements’)
2. calculations

Comment: That sounds like it comes from a scientific source. But I can't tell which is which. Do the two items tell you two different measurements or two different measures? Or is just the first one a measurement? What you wrote is ambiguous. Also can you give a lot more detail to help explain?

Comment: Measures are the thing to do, and the measurement is the result. Which is not the same as the measurand.

Comment: OK, that's one way to differentiate but only choosing one (of many) definition of each word. You should elaborate your explanation, aided possibly by a quote from dictionary entries. (ie as a native speaker and STEM practitioner, your answer only vaguely sounds like maybe it could be right but I'd have to do a lot of dictionary research to compare). You should make your answer self contained, doing that research for the reader.

Comment: This is just completely wrong. Calculations are neither measures nor measurements. Detections may or may not be measurements, but they are not measures.

Comment: Definition of measure is “an action planned or taken to achieve a desired result” -MW. Metric of a tensor is a measure even though you calculate it, volume and area are still measures (really measurands) even though you can calculate them. Measurements are the result, whether they’re detections or calculations. Measures are the actions.