# Measures: calculations vs measurements or calculations vs detections

Tags: computing, measure-phrases

QUESTION: In sampling, are measurements (see context) only ever down to just being detections?

I understand that measures overall include things like calculations and measurements (detections as posed by my question). For example I would use sensors to take ‘measurements’ or detections if it’s less confusing.

CONTEXT: On the topic of measures, things that are measured (‘measurements’) by, for example, weighing on a scale are not the same as things that are calculated (‘calculations’) like, for example, by using parametric models.

Yet confusingly, it is also claimed/assumed in the below that measures include calculations and measurements (first ref), and that calculations are measures (second + third ref).

REF-1: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56402/440001

REF-2: https://mmshub.cms.gov/sites/default/files/Measure-Calculations.pdf

REF-3: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.0.0?topic=measures-define-calculated-measure

Comment: A *measure* is not the same as a *measurement*, you seem to be confusing the two words. Look at some dictionaries and you'll see that *measure* has a lot more meanings, some of which are similar to *measurement* but many are not.

Comment: This is without getting into the philosophical issue of whether you can ever have a measurement that does not involve judgment or theory, or whether measurements always involve some form of analysis and processing (including calculation). That would be one for the philosophers of science.

Comment: The OP's first reference is to the least favourite answer of a popular question. The second reference, on first read of the front page, is using 'measure' quite differently, and is interested in 'quality' based on scores and ratings, not on physically measurable properties of an object.

Comment: It may be relevant to point out that just because two words are "synonyms" in one context doesn't mean they're synonymous in other contexts (few if any pairs of English words are synonymous in *all* contexts). But what's the actual *question* here?

Comment: Downvote for "REF-3: 'measures must be taken'" .   What is that supposed to show?  It's  a sentence without context.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "detections". I can detect that my dog needs to go outside, but that's certainly not a measurement.

Comment: #2 and #3 address measures, not measurements. Yes, normally we detect measurements directly, but can add some math to get a finer result. In #3, the word *measures* is a general term for attempts, not physical lengths. Although you can even use *lengths* figuratively to mean extensive efforts.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, that detection is because of your body’s sensor (sensory stuff vision smell hearing) which is exactly inline, imo, with what is commonly called a measurement. We use sensors to obtain “measurements”

Comment: @Tim do I need to remove the third reference to go back to zero? I agree I didn’t do a good job explaining what I meant there

Comment: The difference you're seeing in both of those examples is using measure as a verb and using it as a noun. As a verb, you can measure something, like you can measure your weight (this is, as you put it, detecting by way of measuring). As a noun you can take a measure, or report a measure, or calculate a measure. In this second context the word is used in a similar way to "parameter".